# Флаг переполнения, нужна помощь!

Tags: ассемблер

Не могу разобраться с Of флагом.
Вопрос исходя из примера, почему при получении отрицательного числа в одном случае он устанавливается, в другом нет?

Пример:

```
mov cx, 80h
sub cx, 7FFFh ;cx = 8081h (Of = 0)

mov cx, 80h
sub cx, 8000h ;cx = 8080h (Of = 1)

; диапазон 8000h - 8080h дает флаг Of = 1 

mov cx, 80h
sub cx, 8080h ;cx = 8000h (Of = 1)

; далее Of = 0, результат положительный
```

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Проще все-таки сначала изучить документацию на инструкции, а потом задавать вопросы. Или хотя бы прочитать популярные статьи, например, из [википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overflow_flag). А иначе получается, что вы даже вопрос понятным образом сформулировать не можете. Не ясно, что вас удивляет и при чём здесь `CX`.